# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "al fin y al cabo"?

Tags: etimología, modismos

La expresión fijada "al fin y al cabo" en inglés sería algo como "at the end of the day, in the end, after all".

Pero quería saber, ¿se conoce la etimología? En la entrada *"[al fin y al cabo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/al_fin_y_al_cabo)"* en Wiktionary, hay algo sobre los significados de los términos como "cabo", por ejemplo, pero no explica cómo se relacionan con el significado de la expresión...

Entonces, ¿cuál es la historia de esa expresión? ¿Cómo evolucionó? Por favor, poned las referencias también.

---

The fixed expression "al fin y al cabo" in English would be something like "at the end of the day, in the end, after all".

But I wanted to know, is the etymology known? The entry *"[al fin y al cabo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/al_fin_y_al_cabo)"* in the Wiktionary lists some meanings for the terms like "cabo", for example, but it doesn't explain how those are related to the meaning of the expression...

So, what is this expression story? How did it evolve? Please, provide some references.

Comment: I'm not answering because I couldn't find any reference. It's just a way to emphasize the meaning, "cabo" means end too, the lit. trans. would be At the end and at the end. There are a lot of expressions in Spanish that emphasize by repeating, in some way, the first word.

Comment: @Laura Thanks for the comment. :) Well, that could be a hint or a starting point. :D

Comment: No creo que se trate de una etimología, es más bien una frase, un dicho para denotar algo resolutivo, al fín y al cabo es solo español. En inglés puede usarse como la frase "at the end" at the end is only spanish.

Comment: An English phrase that also has a doubled-for-effect content is “What all is said and done”.

Comment: Para mi " al fin y al cabo " tiene que ver con la graduación de los suboficiales. El grado más bajo es el de cabo. Entonces creo que tiene relación con eso.

Comment: Creo que hace referencia al accidente geográfico. "Al fin y al cabo" podría decir un marinero de un barco para hacer referencia a que al llegar a un Cabo, se llego al fin de un continente. Suena logico

Answer (score 10):

Las expresiones redundantes como “al fin y al cabo” (“al fin y al fin”) se llaman en castellano **dobletes sinonímicos** y son comunes en muchas lenguas. Son un recurso retórico.

Otros ejemplos de dobletes sinonímicos en español:

> Contante y sonante
>
> Corriente y moliente
>
> Contra viento y marea
>
> Sin oficio ni beneficio
>
> Sin ton ni son
>
> De modo y manera
>
> De golpe y porrazo
>
> De rompe y rasga

La mayoría de estas expresiones son de origen popular y buscan el efecto enfático de la repetición de la misma idea.

De origen popular es con toda probabilidad “al fin y al cabo” que es una expresión de uso corriente al menos desde el siglo XVI, según el CORDE (Corpus Diacrónico del Español).

Parece ser que los dobletes sinonímicos tampoco son raros en inglés:

> Bound and determined
>
> Ranting and raving
>
> Cease and desist
>
> Null and void
>
> Fine and dandy
>
> Well and good
>
> Fair and just
>
> Lo and behold
>
> Free and clear

Answer (score 6):

Aunque no es una respuesta precisa, sí te puede dar una idea del origen. "Cabo" en este caso significa "fin" http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=cabo así que está repitiendo lo mismo, está intensificando.

Aquí se da una pista sobre el origen de expresiones similares:

> http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=41918#168275
>
> En alguna otra ocasión —cuando, por ejemplo, nos hemos referido a
>   expresiones tales como de a pa, de ciento en viento y otras análogas—
>   he manifestado mi opinión de que estamos en presencia de frases hechas
>   que empleamos cuando queremos cargar la intención sobre una idea
>   —aquí, la de ausencia de elementos superfluos—. En esos casos, solemos
>   expresar la idea dos veces y así nacen fórmulas geminadas de
>   encarecimiento o intensificación. Entre ellas, *de modo y manera*, *al
>   fin y al cabo*, *de golpe y porrazo*...

Answer (score 2):

Del diccionario de la Real Academia de la Lengua:

> [cabo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6S13ycd)
>   1. m. Cada uno de los extremos de las cosas.
>   "al cabo"
>   1. loc. adv. Al fin, por último.

Otra expresión sinónima: "al fin y a la postre", precisamente porque el postre es el final de la comida.

Así que, sin que se conozca su origen, la expresión usa dos términos que indican lo mismo para dar énfasis.

Answer (score 1):

El origen de la expresión es bastante antiguo al parecer. Se pueden encontrar ocurrencias en [el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=al%20fin%20%3F%20al%20cabo&autor=&titulo=&ano1=1500&ano2=1600&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) de allá por el siglo XVI:

> Algo parece haber dicho, mas por no gastar tiempo y palabras en responder en forma, tomad la doctrina de boca de Sancto Tomás y de otros, que como el libre albedrío del hombre no está constante ni fijo en lo bueno por el fómite que le inclina a lo malo, tuvo necesidad de ayuda para no se dejar vencer; y aun también para bien entender la ley que Dios le puso (como vos alegastes), porque **al fin y al cabo** dice la Sabiduría que los pensamientos de los mortales son tímidos y nuestras providencias inciertas; y para remediar estos peligros vale mucho la guarda de los Angeles, que con buenas inspiraciones guían a lo bueno y apartan de lo malo y estorban mucho del mal, que el demonio desea hacernos; y en conclusión entended que todo lo deste mundo gobierna Dios mediantes los Angeles, hasta las nubes del aire.
>
> - Juan de Pineda, "Diálogos familiares de la agricultura cristiana", España (1589)

Para que luego hablemos de frases largas. La expresión "cabo" como sinónimo de fin (y como "extremo de la cuerda") se usaba [ya en el siglo XIII](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=al%20cabo&autor=&titulo=&ano1=1200&ano2=1300&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) para determinar la finalización de periodos de tiempo:

> Non te deuo responder, quar tiengo priuilegio del rey que non pague a ninguno su deuda entro **al cabo** del aynno.
>
> - Anónimo, "Vidal Mayor", España (c. 1250)

Aunque también para otros menesteres:

> Pero **al cabo** non pudieron los de Syria con los grandes poderes del & conquistolos Nabuchodonosor.
>
> - Alfonso X, "General Estoria. Cuarta parte.", España (c. 1280)

Aquí significa simplemente "al final" (de la batalla o lo que fuera). Curiosamente, la expresión que no se usaba por entonces era "al final", dado que "final" tenía por aquella época el sentido de "último" o "definitivo": "sentencia final", "juicio final". Es en el siglo XV cuando empieza a aparecer la expresión:

> Se anota **al final** de la carta que se dieron otras dos semejantes al licenciado Santacruz, una para Villatoro y Piedrahíta, y otra para Ávila y su obispado.
>
> - Anónimo, "Documentación medieval abulense en el Registro General del Sello", España (1485 - 1488)

La expresión "al fin" sí se recoge en algunos textos [desde finales del siglo XIII](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=al%20fin&autor=&titulo=&ano1=1200&ano2=1300&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), pero en este caso con un sentido más espiritual que físico:

> E por ende, poca cosa que el hombre faga con el saber vale más que mucho con necedad, que algunos demandan el saber no a plazer de Dios & **al fin** tórnalos el saber en su servicio, que el saber es lumbre & la necedad escuridad.
>
> - Anónimo, "Libro del cavallero Cifar", España (1300 - 1305)
>
> Mas **al fin** fue Jalima, la de aquel alto lugar; Que oyeron un clamante que clamaba y decia "Ensalzada será la que leche le daria; Pueblo, si en tí entrara esta luz de bendicion, Serémos todos librados y quitos de perdicion."
>
> Anónimo, "Poema en alabanza de Mahoma", España (c. 1300)
>
> Y por su alta excelencia él nos quiera amparar, Y en esta alta creencia nos deje bien acabar, Y **al fin** de nuesas vidas nos deje testimoniar Aquella noble palabra, que nos podamos salvar.
>
> Anónimo, "Poema en alabanza de Mahoma", España (c. 1300)

Por tanto, y para terminar, parece que la expresión "al fin y al cabo" originalmente trató de aunar en una sola el sentido más etéreo de "al fin" (usado para el final de las vidas, o como sinónimo de "finalmente"), con el sentido más físico de "al cabo" (finales de periodos cortos de tiempo, acontecimientos, o incluso lugares).

Answer (score 0):

> al fin: at the end, from the latin *finis/finem* which means end
>    al cabo: at the cape

And since a cape the end of a land strip reaching into water that's why it is also used to denote 'the end of something'. Spanish is full of similar examples.