# ¿A qué se debe la aparición de la forma "aynno" en textos del siglo XIV?

Tags: ortografía, historia, españa, dialectos, letras

Buscando información para [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18578/12637) a la pregunta sobre el origen de la expresión "al fin y al cabo", me encontré con la forma *aynno* para "año". Buscando el término en el CORDE, me salen cientos de ocurrencias a lo largo de los siglos XIII y XIV. Ejemplos:

> Datas en el capítol de Santa Maria de Pomplona XXº dia de septiembre l'**aynno** de gracia mil trecientos sixanta et seys.
>
> Este fue muy buen rey et drechurero e est enpeço de regnar en Espaynna en el **aynno** que andaba la era en DCCLIV...
>
> Et si passa **aynno** & dia que non uiene aqueill hermano pueden fer cada uno su pro daqueillas lures partes.

E incluso en el siglo XV, aunque ya menos:

> Dado e otorgado ha seydo por Nos, Princesa sobredicha el present pribilegio en nuestra ciudad de Pomplona, a dizeocho dias del present mes de septiembre, l'**aynno** del nascimiento de Nuestro Sennyor Ihesu Christo mil quoatrozientos sixenta nuebe.
>
> De que nos tenemos por bien pagados e por bien entegrados por testimonio deste nuestro recoger, en el quoal auemos puesto nuestros nombres con nuestras propias manos, en el XV día del dicho mes de Jenero, l'**aynno** del Nascimiento de Nuestro Señor mil CCCC XXX.

En el siglo XVI ya no hay ocurrencias. Pensando que sería un caso aislado, busqué otras palabras. Y encuentro cosas como estas:

> Et por esto, cras, dia lunes, **maynana**, ymos al dicho monssen Bertran et al comte de la Marcha et a otros por fazer los retener ata la venida del **seynnor** Rey si podemos, mossen Eustaces, Johan Testador et yo con nuestras **compaynnas**.
>
> Et el Papa recibio bien los mesageros e dixeron le en que manera era perdida **Espaynna** toda.

Concretamente, la forma "seynnor" aparece por miles en textos de aquella época.

La pregunta es: ¿corresponde esta forma *-ynn-* a una versión antigua de la letra ñ? En el siglo XIV esta forma (y la forma *-yn-*) era muchísimo más común que la forma *-nny-*, que apenas cuenta con unas docenas de apariciones en el CORDE ("sennyor", "annyo"), aunque no tanto como la forma *-ny-*, que tuvo un auge en el siglo XIV para luego caer en el XV. Si es así, ¿cómo pasó la *y* a estar detrás del grupo *nn* (o *n*)? Si no, ¿corresponde esta forma a otro lenguaje ibérico que no derivara en el castellano sino en otro?

Mejor expreso este último párrafo con una tabla de apariciones en el CORDE:

```
        1100-1200  1200-1300  1300-1400  1400-1500
--------------------------------------------------
aynno           1        399        470         34
ayno            2        197        211          7
annyo           0          4         54         11
anyo            0         10       1477        730
año            10        962       6398      14616
--------------------------------------------------
seynnor        16       1226        771        169
seynor          2        848        881          3
sennyor         0          4         51          9
senyor          0         44       2011       1211
señor          98       1965       8860      28944
--------------------------------------------------
Espaynna        0          2          5          5
Espayna         0          1          2          0
Espannya        0          0          2          0
Espanya         0          0        464         34
España          6        705        647       2604
--------------------------------------------------
```

Me resulta especialmente llamativo que las palabras "año", "señor" y "España" (escritas con la *ñ*) también aparecen en textos del siglo XII, lo que me hace pensar que los textos correspondan a alguno de los dialectos ibéricos romances que tomaron caminos diferentes al del castellano, o incluso que desaparecieran. Otra opción es que los textos manuscritos originales contuvieran abreviaturas que se transcribieran de forma diferente según la escuela. Aunque en esta imagen del [Vidal Mayor](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidal_Mayor) (Vidal de Canellas, obispo de Huesca, c. 1250) se puede ver realmente la forma manuscrita de *seýnnor* y de *seynnoria*:

[image: Manuscrito]

Comment: Curioso.  Nunca lo había notado, aunque lo que se me ocurre a lo primero es ¿qué tenían los manuscritos?  Sin duda, los textos no quedaron escritos tal cual, porque había muchísimas abreviaturas, y puede que *aynno* sea la representación de *aỹo*.  También, es posible que la palatización de la *nn* induzca una diptongación en la vocal anterior, sobre todo si la *nn* llega a ser más bien semivocal (como ocurre hoy en día en el portugués de Brasil con *nh*).

Comment: @guifa lo de saber qué contenían exactamente los manuscritos (más que las transcripciones) también es una pregunta que me he hecho. ¿Sería posible acceder a manuscritos de la época?

Comment: Algunas páginas del _Vidal mayor_, el primero de los documentos que aparecen en el CORDE, pueden verse en Wikimedia. [Aquí](http://ow.ly/C4Q7305BiHb) puede leerse: "Nos Don Jaumes (...) conte de barçalona et de urgel et seynnor de montperler", y hay más casos en [los demás folios](http://ow.ly/H5Xt305BiMb): "En el nompne del nuestro seynnor (...)", etc.

Comment: @JMVanPelt cierto, y realmente aparece en el texto manuscrito la forma "seýnnor" (juraría que tiene una tilde en la y). ¡Gracias por el enlace!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Es curioso, esa tilde aparece en algunos casos pero no en todos, como puede verse en la misma imagen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En este caso, resulta que la Wikipedia tenía la respuesta.

El [navarroaragonés](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navarroaragon%C3%A9s) era una lengua romance hablada en el valle del Ebro durante la Edad Media. Dentro del navarroaragonés hubo varios dialectos. El [romance navarro](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_navarro), por ejemplo, que se caracterizaba (entre otras cosas) porque los fonemas palatales /ɲ/ (ñ) y /ʎ/ (ll) se representaban mediante i antepuesta (-in-, -ill-, -yll-). Y también el [riojano precastellano](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riojano_precastellano), el cual en la escritura empleaba grafemas navarros: *quoatro* (u muda), *yn/ynn* (por ñ).

Todo esto cuadra, porque los documentos que encontré con estas características eran de las zonas mencionadas (Zaragoza sobre todo). Y el Vidal Mayor es una compilación de los fueros de Aragón. Con lo cual al final la teoría válida era la de que los textos estaban escritos en una lengua ibérica romance diferente a la que generó el castellano.