# ¿Significaban lo mismo "vosotros" y "vos otros" en el siglo XV?

Tags: etimología, pronombres, historia

Curioseando un poco he descubierto hoy que "[vosotros](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c49zchc)" viene de "vos + otros", y no al revés como yo pensaba (creía que "vos" era una abreviatura de "vosotros"). Eso quiere decir que en el español medieval se decía "vos" para la segunda persona del singular, y "vos otros" para la segunda del plural.

Sin embargo, veo en el CORDE este caso del siglo XIII:

> *Algún moro astroso, que sabe encantar,
>
>   fyzo aquel dïablo en syerpe fygurar
>
>   por amor que podiesse **vosotros** espantar:
>
>   con este tal engaño cuydáronnos torvar.*
>
> - Anónimo, "Poema de Fernán González", España (c. 1250)

Y este otro de ya entrado el siglo XVI:

> *Desde oy dia e hora en adelante que esta carta es fecha nos partimos e quitamos e desapoderamos de la tenençia, e posesion e juro, e sennorio, e propriedad dellas, e lo damos e traspasamos en vos, los dichos pobres, para que sea vuestro libre e quito e desenbargado para sienpre jamas, para **vos otros** e vuestros suçesores en la dicha casa de Sant Lazaro.*
>
> - Anónimo, "Carta de cambio [Colección diplomática de Santo Toribio de Liébana]", España (1502)

Es decir, que ambas formas parecieron convivir durante un tiempo. Mi pregunta es si ambas formas (la separada y la que no) significaban lo mismo durante este periodo de tiempo. Dada la formalidad del segundo texto, es como si entre "vosotros" y "vos otros" hubiese la misma diferencia entre "tú" y "vos" (uno coloquial y el otro cortés). ¿Es esto así? ¿O se corresponden con diferentes lenguas romances como pasó al final con lo del *[aynno](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18579/12637)*?

Comment: A mí me parece una simple variación ortográfica, que la ortografía española no se fijó hasta el siglo XVIII.

Comment: Bueno, se decía *vos* tanto para el singular como el plural (como el inglés moderno estándar *you*)  y luego surgió el uso de *vos otros* (junto con *nos* y *nos otros*) que convivió con la forma simple con sentido plural como se ve en tu segundo ejemplo (cuando dice *vos*, refiere a *los dichos pobres* y por lo tanto, sabemos que tiene referente plural.

Answer (score 2):

Los pronombres "nos" y "vos" proceden del latín como pronombres originalmente plurales. Parece que ya en el latín tardío "vos" empezó a usarse con valor singular como marca de respeto, lo mismo que ha pasado con el "vous" francés (puede encontrarse en Internet un artículo firmado por Nóra Rózsavári en que se desarrolla esto en más detalle).

El hecho de que "nos" y "vos" se pudieran utilizar como singulares y como formas de acusativo y dativo (antes de que surgiera "os"), probablemente motivó el que surgieran las formas compuestas "nos otros" y "vos otros" como formas no ambiguas de nominativo plural y que han acabado lexicalizadas como palabras únicas. Sería un proceso similar a lo que está pasando en inglés con formas como "you guys" o "you all", que se han abierto paso en la lengua oral para compensar la pérdida de distinción de número del pronombre "you".

La vacilación entre "vos otros" y "vosotros" sería una mera cuestión ortográfica, sin ninguna diferencia de significado, durante ese proceso de lexicalización.

Answer (score 0):

En efecto se puede decir en un principio se usaba vos para singular y plural.

Basta con darle un vistazo al francés.

> Vous allez manger? (Va a comer? Ésta forma es algo formal)
>
> Vous allez manger? (Van a comer? Ésta forma es la común para ustedes/vosotros)

Entonces vosotros era en un principio dos palabras "vos otros" que viene de "vos alteros" en latín.

La misma explicación se puede aplicar para nosotros.

Aquí puedes encontrar un poco de la etimología de [vosotros](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?vosotros)

Comment: La etimología de "vosotros" es interesante, pero no es exactamente lo que preguntaba en la pregunta. Dado que al parecer las formas "vosotros" y "vos otros" convivieron durante un tiempo, ¿sus significados eran diferentes?

Comment: Hablando del francés, es muy común oír algo como: *Je vais aller manger. Et vous autres?* (Voy a ir a comer. Y vosotros?) *Vous* es el pronombre normal, pero a menudo se usa la palabra *autres* para dar énfasis. Lo mismo pasa con *Nous*: *Allez manger vous, et nous autres allons promener.*