# ¿Por qué decimos que la parte más escogida es la "flor y nata"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Quién no ha oído una frase del tipo:

> En esa reunión estaba la **flor y nata** de la sociedad: reyes, ministros, jueces...

Básicamente, nos referimos al conjunto de población que representa el valor supremo (léase en cuanto a dinero y/o poder).

Leí que en El Quijote ya aperece. Además, la RAE lo recoge en:

> [**flor**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I6Rb5ZS)
>   *Del lat. flos, floris.*
>   ***flor y nata***
>   1. f. flor (‖ parte más escogida). La flor y nata de la sociedad.

Y, creo que sin relación aparente:

> 7. f. Nata que hace el vino en lo alto de la vasija.

Luego en la definición de la otra palabra vemos:

> [**nata**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QHOuYrw)
>   *Quizá de natta, var. del b. lat. matta 'manta'*
>   (...)
>   3. f. Cosa principal y más estimada en cualquier línea.

Por tanto, parece como que tanto *flor* como *nata* se refieran a algo distinguido, por lo que decir *flor y nata* vendría a ser algo así como *lo bueno y mejor*: una reiteración para dar más potencia a lo descrito.

¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿Hay alguna explicación adicional al respecto?

Por cierto, en Fundéu se comenta en [¿Se debe escribir *crème de la crème* en cursiva? ¿Solo la palabra crème o incluimos el artículo femenino?](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/la-creme-dela-creme-15436/):

> La expresión hecha es *crème de la crème*. Se escribe íntegramente en cursiva (aunque si le antecede un artículo este va en redonda, pues no forma parte de ella) y respetando los acentos del francés. También puede reemplazarse por su equivalente español de *flor y nata*, pero carece del sentido irónico con el que a veces se emplea la expresión francesa.

¡Curioso! Parece que *crème de la crème* puede tener un sentido irónico.

Comment: He encontrado en el CORDE un texto anterior a El Quijote que dice: _"(...) y siempre la primera flor y nata es la mejor."_

Comment: @blonfu pues a mí eso me huele a posible respuesta. Con menos que eso he sacado teorías... :-)

Comment: En el diccionario de autoridades ya viene "flor" como "la parte más escogida y selecta de alguna cosa", y "nata" como "lo principal y más estimado en cualquier línea". Pone un ejemplo que es "debe ser la nata de los comedimientos, y la flor de las ceremonias".

Comment: El ejemplo de @blonfu es de c. 1550. De 1552 es este otro: _"En la más propincua parte a los dichos palacios estaban sobre dos mil hijos de señores, que era toda la **flor y nata** de la nobleza de todo el imperio de Motenzuma."_ Y también al revés, este es del Quijote: _"¡Dios te guíe, **nata y flor** de los andantes caballeros!"_

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¿Qué significa la c. antes del año? La he visto cuando buscaba en el CORDE y ahora que la pones tú me pregunto si es relevante.

Comment: @blonfu en textos así, _c._ suele querer decir [_circa_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9J5wSPG). Es decir, se usa para indicar fechas aproximadas.

Comment: @blonfu exacto, la "c" es de "circa", y también puedes encontrar cosas como "a 1550" que sería "antes de 1550".

Comment: Gracias fedorqui y CarlosAlejo. Entonces supongo que es posible que mi ejemplo fuese posterior al de 1552

Comment: Por otra parte siempre he oído esta expresión para referirse a un grupo de personas, a una élite, nunca a cosas.¿Solo se usa con personas?

Comment: Que si *la crème de la crème* tiene un sentido irónico, debes poner en otra pregunta, aparte.

Comment: @aparente001 no era una pregunta, sino una constatación de un hecho explicado por Fundéu.

Comment: @fedorqui - Bien, gracias. // Propuse un edit, rechaza si no va con tu idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En latín no existía una palabra para decir *nata*. *Lactis* era la leche y *cremor* se refería a los caldos espesos. A la capa de leche gruesa que flota se le decía ***flos lactis***, es decir "flor de la leche". Y también se decía *flos olei* ("flor del aceite") y *flos vini* ("la flor del vino"). Esto porque la metáfora de la flor como algo excelente no es algo que apareció en el español, sino que ya venía usándose en latín.

Entonces sí, estás en lo cierto, en "flor y nata" hay una repetición de significados (un "[**doblete sinonímico**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3423/6915)"), como en *al fin y al cabo* y *de golpe y porrazo*.

Comment: Es una palabra que aún existe en ciertas áreas rurales para designar la capa gruesa de algunos caldos.

Comment: @Jaime - En mi experiencia el uso de *nata* para los caldos no se limita a las áreas rurales.

Answer (score 7):

En los comentarios ya hemos atestiguado que la expresión viene de lejos, dado que se usaba ya en el siglo XVI de forma conjunta, en su variante de "flor y nata" y en la de "nata y flor". Sin embargo, por separado van mucho más allá:

> *Et toda la flor de la caualleria de francia es en esta hueste.*
>
> Anónimo, "Gran Conquista de Ultramar", España (1293)

Sin embargo, la pista definitiva nos la da la traducción de los términos al latín. Sabemos que "flor" viene de *flos, floris*. En principio podríamos pensar que por entonces ese término se podía interpretar de forma literal, pero vemos que no es así. En el diccionario de autoridades se manejan las acepciones y sus traducciones por separado, indicando así:

> FLOR. Metaphoricamente significa la parte mas escogida y selecta de alguna cosa, como de un Reino, Provincia, &c. Lat. **Flos**.
>
> NATA. Metaphoricamente se toma por lo principal y mas estimado en qualquier linea. Lat. **Flos**.

Es decir, en latín el término *flos, floris* ya tenía ese significado metafórico. Por tanto, va a ser complicado darle un origen a dicha metáfora. Nos quedamos sencillamente con que la metáfora se extendió a la nata, seguramente por la definición de "flor" con respecto al vino ("la natilla que hace el vino en lo alto de la cuba"), que mezcla los dos términos. Al ser dicha natilla algo que flota por sobre todo el resto del vino, se puede entender ese sentido metafórico de algo que está por encima de lo demás: lo más selecto. Y de ahí a "la flor y nata" hay un paso, como ya atestiguan los documentos de 1550 que llaman "flor y nata" a dicha natilla del vino.

Comment: Me gusta esta respuesta pero no entiendo "luego va a ser complicado darle un origen a dicha metáfora."  Entendería esa sintaxis si la frase empezara así.  Pues bien, te invito a editar tu respuesta para usar frases más sencillas, a la Hemingway, para hacerla accesible a mayor número de lectores aquí en el sitio.

Comment: @aparente001 he editado esa frase. Si crees conveniente editar alguna otra, no dudes en solicitarlo.